# Total variation norm of probability measures related to $L_1$-norm?

Tags: probability, normed-spaces

On Wikipedia the following is stated: [image]

I don't see how, if the set is countable, $$ \delta (P, Q) = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}} \vert P(A) - Q(A)\vert = \frac{1}{2} \vert \vert P- Q\vert \vert _1$$
holds. Can someone explain that identity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, consider the set $G=\{x | P(x) \geq Q(x)\}$.  If you wanted to put together a set $A$ to maximize $P(A)-Q(A)$, you couldn't do better than including all the points $x\in G$ where $P(x)-Q(x)\geq 0$ while excluding all the points $x\not\in G$ where $P(x)-Q(x)\leq 0$, right?  So, the supremum of $P(A)-Q(A)$ is achieved at $A=G$.  By a symmetrical argument, the supremum of $Q(A)-P(A)$ is achieved at $A=G^c$.  Therefore, the supremum of $|P(A)-Q(A)|$ is achieved at either $G$ or $G^c$.

What's less obvious is that this supremum is achieved at both $G$ and $G^c$.  That's because $P$ and $Q$ are both probability measures, so:
$$P(G)-Q(G) = (1-P(G^c))-(1-Q(G^c)) = Q(G^c)-P(G^c)$$
and either one of these is equal to
$$\delta(P,Q) = \sup|P(A)-Q(A)|=P(G)-Q(G)=Q(G^c)-P(G^c)$$

Now, consider the $L_1$ norm:
$$\|P-Q\|_1=\sum_x |P(x)-Q(x)| = \sum_{x\in G}(P(x)-Q(x)) + \sum_{x\in G^c}(Q(x)-P(x))$$
As we established above, both terms on the right-hand side are equal to $\delta(P,Q)$, so:
$$\|P-Q\|_1 = 2\delta(P,Q)$$

Comment: Hi, do you have a reference (i.e. a textbook or a paper) for your proof?

Comment: I don't remember writing this answer, but I would have cited a reference if I'd gotten it from elsewhere, so I think it's my "original" proof.  That being said, it looks like the Wikipedia page in the question has a reference for it:  David A. Levin, Yuval Peres, Elizabeth L. Wilmer, Markov Chains and Mixing Times, 2nd. rev. ed. (AMS, 2017), Proposition 4.2, p. 48, and I was able to verify in an online copy that the proof there is more or less the same as this one, so I think that reference will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes, I saw the proposition 4.2 on page 48, but I have a small doubt... They show this:
\begin{equation} 
\left\lVert \mu-\nu \right\rVert_{1} =
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left| \mu(x)-\nu(x) \right|
\end{equation}
but they do not show either
\begin{equation}
\sup_{A \in \mathcal{X}} \left| \mu(A)-\nu(A) \right| = 
\left\lVert \mu-\nu \right\rVert_{1}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\sup_{A \in \mathcal{X}} \left| \mu(A)-\nu(A) \right| = 
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \left| \mu(x)-\nu(x) \right|
\end{equation}
Right?

Comment: In other words, I cannot see, in their proposition 4.2 on page 48, the part with the supremum, i.e. $\sup_{A \in \mathcal{X}} \left| \mu(A)-\nu(A) \right|$ :-)

Comment: You might be misreading their notation:  when they write $\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}$, that is their notation for the total variation norm $\sup_{A\in \cal{X}}|\mu(A)-\nu(A)|$.  They don't actually use the notation $|\mu-\nu|_1$ for the $L^1$ norm -- they just write out the equivalent sum.

Comment: Ah OK, now it is clearer, thanks :-) Indeed, I. thought that $\left\lVert \mu - \nu \right\rVert_{TV} = \left\lVert \mu - \nu \right\rVert_{1}$, but it is not.